# Javascript setting this.value is altering the temp variable

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a temp variable a THREE.Veector3 which I pass into the creation of an object

```
object[i] = new Object(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
```

In the class Object I have a variable texture which I set to the new THREE.Vector3 called pos

```
function Object(pos){
    this.texture = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:
    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '../img/img.png' ) } ) );

    this.texture.position = pos;

    this.texture.rotation.x = 0;
    this.texture.rotation.y = 1.57;
    this.texture.rotation.z = 1.57;

    this.texture.scale.x = 100;
    this.texture.scale.y = 50;
    this.texture.scale.z = 100;

    this.texture.position.y = 1000;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to pass pos into another object created inside this Object.

```
object2 = new Object2(pos);
```

However pos has been modified to have the y at 1000. I'm not quite sure why this is happening I read some guides on passing variables but I'm still a bit confused on how the pos variable is modified. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your object to always take a clone of the position

```
function Object(pos){
    this.texture = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:
    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '../img/img.png' ) } ) );

    this.texture.position = pos.clone();

    this.texture.rotation.x = 0;
    this.texture.rotation.y = 1.57;
    this.texture.rotation.z = 1.57;

    this.texture.scale.x = 100;
    this.texture.scale.y = 50;
    this.texture.scale.z = 100;

    this.texture.position.y = 1000;
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid creating a new `Vector3` instance: `this.texture.position.copy( pos )`